# How to find a minimum of two columns based on a condition?

Tags: r, minimum

I have a dataframe in R looking like that

```
ID1    <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
Value1 <- c(2,3,5,2,5,8,17,3,5)
ID2 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
Value2 <- c(4,6,3,5,8,1,2,8,10)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(ID1,Value1,ID2,Value2))
```

Now I am searching for the minimum value of the sum of Value1 and Value2 which has a sum of ID1 and ID2 equal or smaller than 9. Thus, it should show me the minimum of the combination of Value1 + Value2 (not needed to be within the same row) without exceding 9 as the sum of ID1+ID2.

The result should point me to the combination of x in Value1 and y in Value2, which together are the lowest potential values under the condition that ID1+ID2 are <=9.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast replies! I am afraid made a mistake in my original post. I do not need the minimum based on the rowsums but the minimum of a combination of any Value1 + Value2, independent of rows. So the minimum might also be row 1 Value1 + row 8 of Value2 as long as the condition ID1+ID2 <= 10 is true. Does this change the approach?

Comment: Please edit your original post so this is reflected.

Comment: I alredy did, hopefully it is clearer now

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could define the expected result as a mock table or data frame.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know how the output look like in R. For me it would be pretty much enough to point me to the Value1 and Value2 or the ID1 and ID2, where the desired minimum within the condition is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility

```
library(dplyr)
goodrow <- filter(df, ID1 + ID2 <= 9) %>% mutate(sumval = Value1 + Value2) %>% filter(sumval == min(sumval))
```

If I understand well your question, consider using the crossing function. This will compute all the combination of ID1 and ID2

```
library(dplyr)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(ID1,Value1))
df2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(ID2,Value2))
df_test <- crossing(df, df2)


goodrow <- filter(df_test, ID1 + ID2 <= 9) %>% mutate(sumval = Value1 + Value2) %>% filter(sumval == min(sumval))
```

Comment: Can this approach be edited, so that the combination of Value1+Value2 does not need to be within the same row? It is not needed as a rowSum but as an independent sum of any Value1 + any Value2 whereby the corresponding ID1+ID2 is <= 9.

Comment: @Josh why not then just take the global minimum of `ID1` and `ID2`, independent of each other?

Comment: Lets say, the values of Value1 + Value2 are potential expenses of two years and I can add a limited sum to reduce the expenses. Now I need to find the best distribution of this sum (=9 in the above example, which can be used for ID1 and or ID2) to get the minimum of expenses for both years. So there are not indepedent.

Comment: @Josh I just edited it. Hope it answer your question. Not very clean code if you need to do it on big dataset, but you can give a try.

Comment: @FlavienPETIT Thanks for the reply! This is pretty much what I was looking for. The original dataframe is 4992 rows, so it is small enough to do with the crossing() function - resulting in ~25millions rows. I wonder if there are other ways if I got bigger dataframes, but this is the solution I need for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For your specific case

```
which.min(rowSums(df[rowSums(df[,c("ID1","ID2")])<10,c("Value1","Value2")]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a SQL query to answer the question with the `sqldf` package

```r
library(sqldf)
#> Loading required package: gsubfn
#> Loading required package: proto
#> Loading required package: RSQLite
df <- structure(list(ID1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), Value1 = c(2, 
3, 5, 2, 5, 8, 17, 3, 5), ID2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), 
    Value2 = c(4, 6, 3, 5, 8, 1, 2, 8, 10)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))

# just get min sum
sqldf('
select
  min(a.Value1 + b.Value2) as min_sum
from
  df a
  join df b 
    on a.ID1 + b.ID2 <= 9
')
#>   min_sum
#> 1       3
 
# show the rows where min sum occurs
sqldf('
select
  a.Value1
  , b.Value2
  , a.ID1
  , b.ID2
from
  df a
  join df b 
    on a.ID1 + b.ID2 <= 9
group by
  1 = 1
having
  a.Value1 + b.Value2 = min(a.Value1 + b.Value2)
')
#>   Value1 Value2 ID1 ID2
#> 1      2      1   1   6
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Another one liner,

```
filter(transform(df, 'new' = df$Value1 + df$Value2),(df$ID1 + df$ID2 <=9)&(new == min(new)))
```